# Skip and take method in List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, skip

I have a class `Players`. And I want to create `Hyperlink` with `Skip` and `Take` methods. But gives me `System.Linq.Enumerable` error. My goal is make a pyramid user list. here is my codes

```
public class Players
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Order{ get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}



List<Players> playerlist= new List<Players>();
playerlist= (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
             select new Players()
             {
                 Name= (dr["name"].ToString()),
                 Order= int.Parse(dr["order"].ToString()),
                 ID = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString())
             }).ToList();

playerlist= playerlist.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();

int skip = 0;
int take = 1;
int addedCount = 0;

do
{   
    HyperLink links= new HyperLink();
    links.Text = "" + playerlist.Skip(skip ).Take(take).Select(x => x.Name);
    links.NavigateUrl = "playerdetails.aspx?id=" + oyunculistesi.Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => x.ID);
    Page.Controls.Add(links);
    addedCount += take ;
    skip+= take ;
    take += +1;
}
while (addedCount < playerlist.Count);
```

It is working with `StringBuilder` but with `HyperLink` not.

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", players.Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => $"{x.Order}) {x.Name}")));
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us the exact error message received?

Comment: And where did you get that _oyunculistesi_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) is returning an [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) of `char` and you need to build a string from them by using `string.Join` like what you did in the `StringBuilder`:

```
linkuret.Text = string.Join("" , playerlist.Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => x.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your loop in this way

```
    int skip = 0;
    while (skip < playerlist.Count)
    {

        HyperLink links= new HyperLink();
        Players p = playerlist.Skip(skip).FirstOrDefault();
        links.Text = $"{p.Name}" 
        links.NavigateUrl = $"playerdetails.aspx?id={p.Id}"
        Page.Controls.Add(links);
        skip++;
    }
```

First I have removed the Take part from your code and used FirstOrDefault to get always the first element after the skip. Finally the Players elements is loaded just one time and then I used the properties of the class with more readable code.